# How to add custom php file in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I just create a custom theme for WordPress and this is my directory.

```
theme/
 -index.php
 -header.php
 -footer.php
 -terms.php
```

Now I want to make in index.php file have like

```
<a href="/terms">Terms</a>
```

but this doesn't work.
How can I make this when the user clicks terms to redirect him on terms.php file?

Comment: This isn't really how WordPress works. A theme tells WP how to present your pages, but the pages themselves should be added via the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

actually you should create a Page in your admin menu for Terms and then link what what you want to that Page you created.
but before that I think you should learn more about wordpress and how it manage files and templates.